# Vue SSR: ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, localstorage, ssr

Суть в том что я не могу получить доступ к localStorage я понимаю что он не доступен со стороны сервера.
И хотелось бы узнать есть ли вариант проверки как `process.browser` в Nuxt.
`process.browser` и `process.isClient` сейчас имеют значение `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле все оказалось более чем просто.
Таким образом мы проверяем `window` и если он не равен `undefined` то мы уже на стороне клиента
Таким же образом можно проверить доступность `document` и ясное дело `window`

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // 
}
```

Или же вариант проверки через `Vue.prototype`

```
Vue.prototype.$isServer
//Внутри компонента
this.$isServer
```

Решение нашел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255288/vue-js-server-side-rendering-document-is-not-defined)